# SQL Server Table Partitioning Authorization

Tags: sql-server, authorization, privileges, partition, data-partitioning

Can partition-based user privilege be given? Is partition-based user authorization possible? Can we do partition-based authorization in SQL Server, not table-based?

For example; You define 1 table to consist of 5 partitions. Then we want to define different user privileges for these partitions. Is this possible?

Comment: Not likely but without details that is just guessing. Partitioning of a table is invisible to the user and to any SQL used to query the table - seems you might have a mistaken idea of the purpose of partitioning?

Comment: For example, I do country-based partitioning. I don't want the countries I partitioned to see each other's data.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality isn't present natively, but you can accomplish this with a view on top of your data.

```sql
USE tempdb;

CREATE USER UserA WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER UserB WITHOUT LOGIN;

CREATE TABLE dbo.CountryAuthorization (
    ISOCountryCode CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    AuthorizedUser sysname NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_CountryAuthorizations PRIMARY KEY (AuthorizedUser, ISOCountryCode)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CountryData (
    ISOCountryCode CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Nonce VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_CountryData__Nonce DEFAULT REPLICATE('x', 50)
);
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_CountryData
AS
    SELECT d.*
    FROM dbo.CountryData AS d
    JOIN dbo.CountryAuthorization AS a
        ON a.ISOCountryCode = d.ISOCountryCode
    WHERE a.AuthorizedUser = USER_NAME();
GO
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.vw_CountryData TO PUBLIC;

INSERT INTO dbo.CountryAuthorization
(
    ISOCountryCode,
    AuthorizedUser
)
VALUES
    ('US', 'UserA'),
    ('CA', 'UserA'),
    ('US', 'UserB');

INSERT INTO dbo.CountryData
(
    ISOCountryCode
)
VALUES
    ('US'),
    ('CA');

EXECUTE AS USER = 'UserA'
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vw_CountryData;
REVERT;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'UserB'
SELECT *
FROM dbo.vw_CountryData;
REVERT;
```

The idea here is that the users are given explicit authorization to a particular country's data in the `dbo.CountryAuthorization` table which the view checks. So long as your users don't have the ability to query the base table, this should work.